# How to close currently open app when click on push notification

Tags: android, android-fragments, push-notification

I have question regarding how to close app when user click on notification from tray and open activity.
Whole scenario like below:
for example my application name is `testdemo`.

Suppose `testdemo` application is currently opened and user doing some work in application. At that time a push notification arrived that is related to `testdemo` application.

In this case user already opens `testdemo` application but when click on notification its open `testdemo` application again. But i want to close currently application and than open application. Because of when new application is close that also `testdemo` app , but last screen already open that is before notification clicked by user.

My send notification looks like this:

```
 private void sendNotification(String title,
                              String message,
                              String receiverUid) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("uid", receiverUid);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, ++NOTIFICATION_ID, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_alert)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(++NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can easily open current state of application without new instances of it. 
   sample of the code to setup your launch intent:

> ```
> >  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
> >         public Intent launchIntent(Context ctx) {
> >                 final ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
> >                 Intent intent = new Intent();
> >                 boolean activated = false;
> >                 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) { 
> >                     List<ActivityManager.AppTask>  tasks = am.getAppTasks();
> >                       for (ActivityManager.AppTask task: tasks){
> >                           intent = task.getTaskInfo().baseIntent;
> >                           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
> >                           activated = true;
> >                           break;
> >                       }
> >                 } else {
> >                     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
> >                     final List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTaskInfos = am.getRecentTasks(1024,0);
> >                     String myPkgNm = ctx.getPackageName();
> >                     if (!recentTaskInfos.isEmpty()) {
> >                          RecentTaskInfo recentTaskInfo;
> >                          final int size = recentTaskInfos.size();
> >                          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
> >                              recentTaskInfo = recentTaskInfos.get(i);
> >                              if (recentTaskInfo.baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName().equals(myPkgNm))
> > {
> >                                  intent = recentTaskInfo.baseIntent;
> >                                  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
> >                                  activated = true;
> >                              }
> >                          }
> >                     }
> >                 }
> >                 if (!activated) {
> >                     intent = new Intent(this, ALaunch.class);
> >                 }
> >             return intent;
> >         }
> ```

2. You can pass intent extra data with intent and close current activity or app by your trigger.

to pass an extra use:

`intent.putExtra("KEY",value);`

to retrieve use inside `Activity`

`value = getIntent().getExtras().get("KEY");`

3. You can say inside manifest file that this activity has got only a single instance to prevent to open it again.

`android:launchMode=["singleTop" | "singleTask" | "singleInstance"]` choose any prefered. `singleTop` is more useful, imho in your case.

Comment: Thnks for answer. Can you give example or referenced link for get exact idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here i got solution by adding TaskStackBuilder class and changes in manifest file.
please visit below link :

https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html#ExtendedNotification